# Find the number of all ordered pair (a, b) such that a ∈ A, b ∈ B, a is not equal to b and a + b is even [Read Full Q. below]

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility, inclusion-exclusion

Let A denote the set of all numbers between 1 and 700 which are divisible by 3 and let B denote the set of all numbers between 1 and 300 which are divisible by 7. Find the number of all ordered pair (a, b) such that a ∈ A, b ∈ B, a is not equal to b and a + b is even

**My Approach**

Okay so looking at the question, I can tell that I need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle but before applying it, I must dissect the sets. So a + b needs to be even this means that both of them (a,b) must be either even or odd. We can create a subset $p$ from $A$ which are all the even multiples of 3 till 300 and a subset $q$ for all odd multiples of 3. Then do the same for the set $B$ for the multiples of 7 and create subsets $m$, $n$ respectively.

Now we have 4 sets:

- $p$ = {even multiples of 3 till 300}
- $q$ = {odd multiples of 3 till 300}
- $m$ = {even multiples of 7 till 300}
- $n$ = {odd multiples of 7 till 300}

After which I apply the inclusion-exclusion principle to these sets $p ∪ q ∪ m ∪ n$ for which I got $84 - 252 + 189 - 84$ but that makes no sense since the answer would be in negative. There maybe a calculation error but anyway, if you have an easier approach please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll get you most of the way and leave it to you to finish.

The largest and smallest multiples of $3$ in $A$ are $699=3\cdot233$ and $3=3\cdot1$, respectively, so there are $233$ multiples of $3$ in $A$; $116$ of them are even, and $117$ of them are odd.

The largest and smallest multiples of $7$ in $B$ are $294=7\cdot42$ and $7=7\cdot1$, respectively, so there are $42$ multiples of $7$ in $B$; $21$ of them are even, and $21$ of them are odd.

If $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$, $a+b$ is even if and only if either $a$ and $b$ are both even, or $a$ and $b$ are both odd. There are $116\cdot21$ pairs with $a$ and $b$ both even and $117\cdot21$ with $a$ and $b$ both odd, and from this you can easily find the number of pairs such that $a+b$ is even.

However, that includes some pairs for which $a=b$, e.g., the pair $\langle 42,42\rangle$. How many such pairs are there?

Comment: so I guess the final equation would be $(117 * 21) + (116 * 21) - 700$ because there are 700 pairs of same numbers.

Comment: @ShlokJain: You’re subtracting way too much. First off, $B$ has only $300$ elements, so there are only $300$ possible pairs with $a=b$. But even that is way too much, because you can only subtract pairs that you’ve counted twice, i.e., pairs $\langle a,a\rangle$ such that $a\in B$, and $a$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $7$. An integer is a multiple of both $3$ and $7$ if and only if it’s a multiple of $21$. How many multiples of $21$ are there that are less than $300$?

Comment: oh yeah... I feel really dumb right now... there would be 14 of such duplicate pairs. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShlokJain: You’re welcome!